# How to resolve conflict between `sidewaystable` and `statsoc` document class

Tags: rotating

The document class `statsoc` released by the Royal Statistical Society appears to conflict with the `sidewaystable` environment in the `rotating` package. In particular, the following does not compile with document class `statsoc` but compiles fine with `article` or `revtex4`. The document class can be found [here](http://www.statslife.org.uk/files/stylefile14.zip).

```
\documentclass{statsoc}
\usepackage{rotating}

\title{test}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
a&b\\
c&d\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{This is a longer caption with a considerable amount of text. It gets wrapped rather oddly even though there is a lot of space left on the page.}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

The error message is

```
./test.tex:14: LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end
```

which corresponds to `\end{sidewaystable}`.

Do you know why the above does not compile and how to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"interesting" coding in that class...

The error is always generated by a `\\` which is in vertical mode so can not end a line.  You can make it go away by starting a line with `\leavevmode` which gives `\\` something to do. (Simpler is just to edit the class but that may not be an option)

Unfortunately you need a different number of `\aftergroup` depending if `color` is used, but this seems to work in either case.

Also as requested in the updated question the caption is made wider (the class sets it to `0.33333\textwidth` so just locally set `\textwidth` to 3 time the required caption width).

```
\documentclass{statsoc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\author{me}
\title{test}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}


{\textwidth=3\linewidth
\caption{This is a longer caption with a considerable amount of text. It gets wrapped rather oddly even though there is a lot of space left on the page.
\ifx\color\undefined\else
\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup
\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup
\aftergroup
\aftergroup
\fi
\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup
\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup
\aftergroup
\leavevmode}}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
a&b\\
c&d\\
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help on getting the document to compile. I have a final question: The width of the caption is extremely small such that even a short caption gets wrapped onto multiple lines. Do you have thoughts on how to resolve that issue? I have updated the original question with a longer caption that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: As with any journal class are you sure that you should be changing this? The whole point of such a class is to remove control from the author. It must for example be possible just to re-instate the standard table/caption behaviour but if that prevents submission then... (and if it isn't for submission best to use a more normal class, journal classes are always weird and written to meet often undocumented internal processing needs.)

Comment: Normally, I would not try to change the definitions of the journal. However, I would like to have the layout of `sidewaystable` consistent with the layout of `table` whose caption spans the full width of the page. I imagine the funny wrapping is another artefact of `rotating` and `statsoc` not being compatible.

Comment: @TillHoffmann updated answer:-)